# var within a function as parameter of another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, var

I use javascript, and I have trouble with var wrapped in a function.

Code is as below:

```
function submitData() {
    let s = dataSaveParam();
    if (s != '') {
        popupConfirm('sure you want to submit?', function() {
            saveDataToDB(s);
        });
    }
}
```

`submitData()` run twice. In the first time, `dataSaveParam()` returns **1**, and the second time returns **2**.
The value of `s` got from `saveDataToDB()` is always 1, which means `s`  just remains unchanged.

Comment: No, the closure in the code you posted is fine, `s` is not a global shared variable. But maybe there's a bug in `dataSaveParam` or `popupConfirm` or `saveDataToDB`.

Comment: I agree with Bergi. Can't tell what the issue is without seeing the other functions.

Comment: the problem is probably in `dataSaveParam()` try `console.log(s)` and check if it always 1 or 2

Comment: Oh man u r a genius! I checked just now and really found a stupid bug in my function popupConfirm. Now it's working perfect. Again, thanks for you kind help!

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys! It's indeed the problem of popupConfirm instead of closure